# ng-repeat not listing movie titles

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a simple movie app in Angular. I can do a JSON request to the tmdb (the movie database) api and show the raw result on my homepage. But my problem is that I can't seem to only show the title of the movies from the JSON request.

examplecontroller.js.coffee

```
angular.module('app.exampleApp').controller('exampleCtrl', [

  '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    var service = '/movie/popular';
    var apiKey = 'a8f703963***065942cd8a28d7cadad4';
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback;

    $scope.movieList = 'requesting...';

    $http.jsonp(url).then(function(data, status) {
      $scope.movieList = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log($scope.movieList)
    },function(data, status) {
      $scope.movieList = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
  }
]);
```

show.html.haml

```
#search{"ng-app" => "app.exampleApp"}
  %div{"ng-controller" => "exampleCtrl"}
    %div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList track by $index"}
      {{movie.title}}
```

When I check the elements in Chrome I see that I have about 25.000 ng-repeat divs. But all without content.

I've been following [this](http://eluleci.github.io/blog/angularjs/2014/09/17/getting-data-angular-http.html) tutorial for a bit (and some other sources) and something I don't understand is the `movie in Movielist`. I know that movielist is the whole json request but what is movie?

**Solved**

controller

```
angular.module('app.exampleApp').controller('exampleCtrl', [

  '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    var service = '/movie/popular';
    var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4';
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback;

    $scope.movieList = [];

    $http.jsonp(url).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {
          $scope.movieList = data.results;
          console.log($scope.movieList)
        } else {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        }

      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
      });
    }
]);
```

show

```
%h1
  Logo
%li
  = link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)

#search{"ng-app" => "app.exampleApp"}
  %div{"ng-controller" => "exampleCtrl"}
    %div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList"}
      {{ movie.original_title }}
```

Comment: remove the track by $index and check

Comment: As regards the explanation about `movie in MovieList`, movie is juste the name of your object for this raw. Like in a `foreach` you have the list and the name of the object. Movie will be like movieList[i].

Comment: When you call `ng-repeat = 'movie in movieList"` you are assigning the variable `movie` to the element pointed at by the iterator.

Comment: Try to print whole movie object like {{movie}}

Comment: @soosmca without the $index is get the following error `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: movie in movieList, Duplicate key: string:e, Duplicate value: e`

Comment: @PareshGami if I do {{ movieList }} I get all the data from the JSON request.

Comment: Just print {{movie}} within ng-repeat and please paste json in comment which is display

Comment: don't `stringify` the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are taking the javascript array returned to the request callback as `data` and converting it into a string using `JSON.stringify()`.

Then when you pass this string to `ng-repeat` it is looping over every character in that string. Thus you have a huge number of repeated `<div>` but since each is a string containing one character there is no `title` property of that string to print

Pass the array directly to your scope variable in the request callback.

Change:

```
$scope.movieList = JSON.stringify(data);
```

To:

```
$scope.movieList = data;
```

JSON is a string data format. When `$http` receives that string response it will internally parse it to a javascript object/array. You should not need to transform it yourself

Comment: Yea that makes sence thanks. But I still have some problem showing the data. 

I've unstringed the data and show it like this, `#search{"ng-app" => "app.exampleApp"}
  %div{"ng-controller" => "exampleCtrl"}
    %div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList track by $index"}
      {{ movie }}`

This shows the data of the JSON in my div.

If I do {{ movie.title }} it still doesn't show the title.

Comment: what does data structure look like? get the idea out of your head that it is json in the view... it is a javascript array of javascript objects now

Comment: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&callback=angular.callbacks._0 This is the output of the JSON file.

Comment: because the array you want is in the property `results` ... `$scope.movieList = data.results;`

Comment: Took me a while but it's fixed now. Cheers!